# Advance reporting is empty

Tags: magento2, advanced-reporting

Advance reporting is working fine but suddenly it is showing empty and on store views it's showing only all store views.
[image: advance reporting]

Thanks

Comment: To be honest this advance reporting is broken

Comment: how to resolve it ?